# Postgre SQL data to XML format

Tags: xml, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to convert the Postgre SQL data to XML format by using the following:

```
copy(
select xmlroot
(
    xmlelement
    (
        name "warehouses",
        xmlagg
        (
            xmlelement
            (
                name "warehouse",
                xmlelement(name "id",warehouse.w_id),
                xmlelement(name "name",warehouse.w_name),
                xmlelement
                (
                    name "address",
                    xmlelement(name "street",warehouse.w_street),
                    xmlelement(name "city",warehouse.w_city),
                    xmlelement(name "country",warehouse.w_country)
                ),
                xmlelement
                (
                    name "items",
                    xmlagg(
                    xmlelement
                    (   
                        name "item",
                        xmlelement(name "id",item.i_id),
                        xmlelement(name "im_id",item.i_im_id),
                        xmlelement(name "name",item.i_name),
                        xmlelement(name "price",item.i_price),
                        xmlelement(name "qty",stock.s_qty)
                    ))
                )
            )
        ) 
    ), version '1.0" encoding = "utf-8'
) from warehouse inner join stock on warehouse.w_id = stock.w_id
                  inner join item on stock.i_id = item.i_id
) to '/home/cs4221/Desktop/test.xml'
```

But shows the error message:

> "aggregate functions call can not be nested"

And point to my second xmlagg function.

Why the xmlagg can not be nested called?

Without the second xmlagg, the output looks like this:

```
<warehouses>
<warehouse>
    <id>22</id>
    <name>Namekagon</name>
    <address>
        <street>Anniversary</street>
        <city>Singapore</city>
        <country>Singapore</country>
    </address>
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>4</id>
            <im_id>54868007</im_id>
            <name>MECLIZINE HYDROCHLORIDE</name>
            <price>54.49</price>
            <qty>597</qty>
        </item>
    </items>
</warehouse>
<warehouse>
    <id>22</id>
    <name>Namekagon</name>
    <address>
        <street>Anniversary</street>
        <city>Singapore</city>
        <country>Singapore</country>
    </address>
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>5</id>
            <im_id>24658312</im_id>
            <name>Doxycycline Hyclate</name>
            <price>28.99</price>
            <qty>477</qty>
        </item>
    </items>
</warehouse>
```

Warehouse id 22 has two item 4 and 5. I want to aggregate them to the same section.

Comment: Can you give us an example, what the output should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one xmlagg per select.
To get around this you can use a subselect in an xmlelement and use the next level xmlagg there.

Just remove the join at the and of the query and use something like:

```
  xmlelement
  (
    name "items", 
    (  
      select xmlagg
      (
        xmlelement
        (   
          name "item",
          xmlelement(name "id",item.i_id),
          xmlelement(name "im_id",item.i_im_id),
          xmlelement(name "name",item.i_name),
          xmlelement(name "price",item.i_price),
          xmlelement(name "qty",stock.s_qty)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  from stock where warehouse.w_id = stock.w_id 
    join item on stock.i_id = item.i_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<warehouses>
<warehouse>
    <id>22</id>
    <name>Namekagon</name>
    <address>
        <street>Anniversary</street>
        <city>Singapore</city>
        <country>Singapore</country>
    </address>
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>4</id>
            <im_id>54868007</im_id>
            <name>MECLIZINE HYDROCHLORIDE</name>
            <price>54.49</price>
            <qty>597</qty>
        </item>
    </items>
</warehouse>
<warehouse>
    <id>22</id>
    <name>Namekagon</name>
    <address>
        <street>Anniversary</street>
        <city>Singapore</city>
        <country>Singapore</country>
    </address>
    <items>
        <item>
            <id>5</id>
            <im_id>24658312</im_id>
            <name>Doxycycline Hyclate</name>
            <price>28.99</price>
            <qty>477</qty>
        </item>
    </items>
</warehouse>
```

Comment: warehouse id 22 has two item 4 and 5. i want to aggregate them to the same section. i used xmlagg but got the error message: "aggregate functions call can not be nested" (above output is got by removing the second xmlagg function)